# Why does VBA see all bulleted items as part of the same List object?

Tags: vba, ms-word, bulletedlist

I am editing a Word document with five separate lists of bulleted items. If I reference, in my VBA code:

```
ActiveDocument.Lists(1).Range
```

then it refers to the entire section of the document from the first item in the first list to the last item in the last list.

If for some `i > 1`, I reference:

```
ActiveDocument.Lists(i)
```

in my code, then I get an error.

How could I fix my document so that each of the five bulleted lists in my document has a different index from 1 to 5?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to replicate by:

1. Adding a bulleted list
2. In the *middle* of the list, turning off bullets on one of the items.
3. Typing some text on the now non-bulleted line.

When I do so, the corresponding `List` entry encompasses the range including the non-bulleted line in the middle.

I think the most realistic answer to your question is to save your document as a plain text file, open that, and re-apply the bullets where you want them.  I am not finding anything online that talks about splitting an existing `List`.

That said, as far as I can tell, a non-bulleted line within the range of a `List` has `Range.ListFormat.ListTemplate` equal to `Nothing`, unlike the bulleted lines.  So one option would be to iterate over your `List` record and store separate ranges, breaking based on `ListTemplate`.  For example, the following function selects the lines in `Lists(1)` up to the first non-bulleted line (quick hack; YMMV):

```
Public Sub SelectList1()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = ActiveDocument.Lists(1).Range
    Dim p As Paragraph, foundit As Boolean
    foundit = False

    For Each p In r.Paragraphs
        If p.Range.ListFormat.ListTemplate Is Nothing Then
            foundit = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next p

    If foundit Then
        r.End = p.Range.Start
    End If

    r.Select
End Sub
```

For example, with this list created as described above:

```
 * foo
 * bar
bat
 * baz
```

`Lists(1).Range` includes `foo` through `baz`, including the intervening `bar`.  Running `SelectList1` (above) selects the `foo` and `bar` lines, but leaves `bat` and `baz` unselected.

Comment: +1 Very good observation and solution. However, it is better to iterate through all lists in the document instead of only going through the first list `Lists(1)`. On the other hand, *splitting the list* is easy, either change the list style or right-click on the first bullet and select **Separate List**.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa223009(v=office.11).aspx):

> **List Object:** Represents a single list format that's been applied to specified paragraphs in a document.

So if you have more than one list with some non-bulleted paragraph(s) in the middle, the `Range` will start with the first item of the first list and end with the last item of the last list including all non-bulleted paragraph(s) in the middle.

To fix this issue, you need to separate the lists (right-click on the bullet and select **Separate List**).

If you want to do it in code without modifying the document, you will have to iterate though the paragraphs of the `Range` of each `List` and check if it has a `ListFormat.ListTemplate` which indicates that it is a list item, otherwise it is a non-bulleted paragraph. Similar to [cxw's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43396595/3215948), but iterating through all lists in case you have more than one.

This function highlights all list items and ignores the non-bulleted paragraph(s) in the middle:

```
Sub HighlightLists()
    Dim li As Word.List
    Dim p As Paragraph

    For Each li In ActiveDocument.Lists
        For Each p In li.Range.Paragraphs
            If Not p.Range.ListFormat.ListTemplate Is Nothing Then
                p.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
            End If
        Next p
    Next li
End Sub
```